# How can I stop UICollectionView from showing duplicate items after Firebase update

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two UICollection views on a page that displays data about a Room. It includes photos of the room in one UICollection View and another UICollection View which contains a list of items in that room. There's a link to edit the Room. When a user clicks on the link, they then segue to another view that let's them update it including adding additional photos.

After adding a photo, and hitting submit, in the background the photo is uploaded to Firebase storage and in the Firebase database, the record is updated to include the name of the file that was just uploaded. Meanwhile, the user is segued back to the Room view.

There's a watched on the record of the room in Firebase and when it updates, then the view is refreshed with new data. This is where the problem occurs. It appears, based on a lot of debugging that I've been doing, that the Observe method fires twice and what ends up happening, is the UICollection view that holds the images of the room will show duplicates of the last photo added.

For example, if I add one photo to the room, that photo will appear in the collection 2x. I've attempted to clear the array before the array is updated with the images, and from my analysis, it appears that the array only contains two items, despite showing three in the view. I'm not sure what is happening that would cause this?

[Here's a link to the entire file](https://gist.github.com/thehashrocket/65300368dbc7a94ad8eb424dcb095c1e), because I think it might help.

Here's the loadData() method in case this is all that's important:

```
func loadData() {
    self.ref = Database.database().reference()
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    let buildingRef = self.ref.child("buildings").child(userID)

    buildingRef.keepSynced(true)

    buildingRef.child(self.selected_building as String).observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        if ((value) != nil) {
            let building_id = value?["id"] as! String
            let saved_image = value?["imageName"] as! String
            let user_id = userID as! String
            let destination = "/images/buildings/\(userID)/\(building_id)/"
            let slideShowDictionary = value?["images"] as? NSDictionary

            if ((slideShowDictionary) != nil) {
                self.slideShowImages = [UIImage]()
                self.slideShowCollection.reloadData()
                var last_value = ""
                slideShowDictionary?.forEach({ (_,value) in
                    print("are they different? \(last_value != (value as! String))")
                        if (last_value != value as! String) {
                            print("count: \(self.slideShowImages.count)")
                            print("last_value \(last_value)")
                            print("value \(value)")
                            last_value = value as! String
                            CloudStorage.instance.downloadImage(reference: destination, image_key: value as! String, completion: { (image) in
                                self.slideShowImages.append(image)
                                self.slideShowCollection.reloadData()
                            })

                        }
                })

                CloudData.instance.getBuildingById(userId: user_id, buildingId: building_id, completion: { (building) in
                    self.title = building.buildingName as String
                    self.roomsCollection.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
    })

    // User is signed in.
    self.getRooms()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely familiar with the Firebase API but if you are having issues with the observation I would suspect the following:

```
@IBAction func unwindToRoomsVC(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
        loadData()
    }
```

Triggering `loadData` a second time looks like it would add a second observation block. As best I can tell the `.observe` method probably persists the block it is given and triggers it on all changes.

Comment: lol, that was it! I looked right over that . . . multiple times. That extra loaddata loaded a 2nd observer and so there was two of them running at the same time. thank you!!!!!!